# Not able to press the keys in numeric keypad jquery?

Tags: jquery

Hi i have downloaded the numeric keypad from the link http://www.keith-wood.name/keypad.html and i have a jquery dialog box ,When i click the text box inside the dialog box  the numeric key pad displays but not able to press the keys when i press the numeric keypad closes . Thanks in Advance

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#txtPassword').live('click', function (){// better use on at the place of live
     alert("clicked");
     $(this).keypad(); 
   });
 });
```

Comment: but not able to press the keys when i press the numeric keypad closes. its already working as like that

Comment: Its working fine for me just checked, post some code

Comment: sandeep the keys should display on the textbox but its not

Comment: Bharath can u tell wat changes you made to work

Comment: Keep in mind that `.live()` has been deprecated in jQuery since v1.7. I would suggest using `.on()` if you're using jQuery higher that 1.7.

Comment: if i use .on() its not working Brandon

Comment: Could you please create a DEMO JSFIDDLE for this ?